# How to fetch hibernate query result as associative array of list or hashmap

Tags: java, hibernate, struts

I am developing an application in struts 2 and hibernate 3.

I have 3 tables

1. Inspection
2. InspectionMission
3. Timeline

`Inspection` is associated with `InspectionMission` and `InspectionMission` is associated with `Timeline`.

Now I have following problem. I have written following query in HQL

```
public List getQuartewiseInspectionList(){

   Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

   Query q = session.createQuery(
                "select count(i.inspectionId) as tot_inspections,t.year,t.quarter" +
                " From Inspection as i " +
                " inner join i.inspectionMission as im inner join im.timeline as t" +
                " GROUP by t.year,t.quarter");

   return q.list();

}
```

I want to fetch result as following

```
result[0][tot_inspections] = "6"
result[0][year] = "2009";
result[0][quarter] = "Q2";

result[1][tot_inspections] = "3"
result[1][year] = "2009";
result[1][quarter] = "Q3";
```

and so on so that I can display it in jsp struts as follows:

In JSP I have written following code

```
<table border="1">

   <s:iterator value="result" status="status">
       <tr class="<s:if test="#status.even">even</s:if><s:else>odd</s:else>">
             <td class="nowrap"><s:property value="tot_inspections" /></td>
             <td class="nowrap"><s:property value="year" /></td>
             <td class="nowrap"><s:property value="quarter" /></td>
       </tr>         
    </s:iterator>
</table>
```

Can anyone here help me?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You have to use the "new map" syntax [(Hibernate Reference paragraph 14.6)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select-clause)

```
select new map(count(i.inspectionId) as tot_inspections, t.year as year, t.quarter as quarter) from ...
```

The rest of the query is the same. This will return a list of maps, where the key is the alias of the "column".

Comment: Hello Salvatore Insalaco,

Thanks for your answer. I was searching for last 2 days for this solution and your answer provided it to me.

Thanks for the perfect answer.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, but couldn't find in the Hibernate docs.

Comment: Someone please post a link this hibernate topic.

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to define a data object just for displaying those results and let Hibernate create instances of those on the fly. This class would just need a matching constructor.

Example class (getters and fields omitted)

```
public class InspectionCount() {
    // fields
    public InspectionCount(int count, int year, int quarter) {
        // initialize instance
    }
    // getters
}
```

The query would then look

```
select new InspectionCount(count(i.inspectionId), t.year, t.quarter)
        from Inspection as i
        inner join i.inspectionMission as im inner join im.timeline as t
        group by t.year,t.quarter
```

As a result you would get a `List` of `InspectionCount`s.