# How can i get Map object from Hibernate Query

Tags: java, hibernate

Currently i am getting List of Object form Hibernate Query

My code is:

```
session.createSQLQuery("SELECT c.EMP_ID, COUNT(*) FROM employee c WHERE c.CITY=:someCity")
List<Object[]> objList =myQuery.list();
```

Here i am getting only two parameters EMP_ID and COUNT

Is there any way so i can Map
like

```
Map<int empId, int count> objList =myQuery.someMethod();
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876724/how-to-return-mapkey-value-with-hql, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925363/how-to-fetch-hibernate-query-result-as-associative-array-of-list-or-hashmap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your Query as follows:

> "SELECT new map(c.EMP_ID as empId, COUNT(*) as empCount) FROM employee c WHERE c.CITY=:someCity"

Now this will return you the List of the Map with Keys `empId` & `empCount`.

Here is a quick code snippet:

```
List<?> objList = session.createQuery("SELECT new map(c.EMP_ID as empId, 
                  COUNT(*) as empCount) FROM employee c WHERE c.CITY=:someCity").list();
Iterator<?> myRows = objList.iterator();    
while (myRows.hasNext()) {
    Map row = (Map) myRows.next();
    System.out.println(row);
}
```

Output:

```
{empId=1, empCount=10}
{empId=2, empCount=20}
{empId=3, empCount=30}
```

Comment: It will work only with HQL query not SQL query

Answer (score 2):

As you are using `createSQLQuery`, it will give you a result set of two length arrays. You have to build the map manually, like below

```
for(Object[] row : objList ) {
    map.put(row[0], row[1]);
}
```