# Hibernate select only some fields and mapping to Map

Tags: java, hibernate

I have entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST")
public class TEST implements Serializable {
   ...

    private String f1;
    private String f2;
    private String f3;
   ....
```

I need create select abd get only f1, f2 fields.

```
public Map<Stirng, String> getTestF1AndF2() {
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        try { 
            Session mySession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Query q = mySession.createSQLQuery("SELECT f1, f2 from TEST");
            //???????????????
            //fill map 
            mySession.close();
            return map;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.log(Level.INFO, e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I can use myBatis or another libs but I need use only hibernate. How can I reate this Mapping?

Comment: why do you want to select f1 and f2? If you retrieve the test object, you already have all of f1, f2 and f3

Comment: I found solution
http://stackoverflow.com/a/21757841/5620472

Answer (score 2):

Use below HQL query to get the results as `Map`:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select new map(f1 as f1, f2 as f2) from Test");
List<Map<String,String>> result = query.list();
```

Refer to this similar post:

[How to fetch hibernate query result as associative array of list or hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925363/how-to-fetch-hibernate-query-result-as-associative-array-of-list-or-hashmap)

If you want to use SQL query then use this:

```
Query query1 = session.createSQLQuery("select sname as name, grp as grp from students").setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);

List<Map<String,String>> result = query.list();
```

Note that the queries returns list of values, so result is List of Map elements in it.